# realm.js - Accessing object of type Contact which has been invalidated or deleted with NO stack trace

Tags: react-native, realm, react-navigation

Would (really) appreciate help on this one.

I have a realm listView which navigates away to a detailed view.

The detailed view is deleting the entry from the original list view and navigate back. I have registered listeners on the realm DB change to update the content of the list view.

Here is the code I'm using, which, after delete get an exception - "Accessing object of type Contact which has been invalidated or deleted" after the navigation occurs.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Also, it seems that the change listener (updateContactsFromDB) is called twice, while deleting just one object - ideas?

10x

```
ContactPage.js:

export default class ContactsPage extends Component {
  updateContactsFromDB(){
    console.log("ContactsPage:updateContactsFromDB()");
    let contacts = Realm.objects('Contact');
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(contacts.snapshot()),
    });
  }
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("ContactsPage:constructor()");
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => (r1 !== r2)});
    let contacts = Realm.objects('Contact');
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(contacts.snapshot()),
    };
     this.updateContactsFromDB = this.updateContactsFromDB.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount(props){
    console.log("ContactsPage:componentWillMount");
    Realm.addListener('change', this.updateContactsFromDB);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(props){
    console.log("ContactsPage:componentWillUnmount");
    Realm.removeListener('change', this.updateContactsFromDB);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("ContactsPage:render()");
    return (
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={(contact) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('ContactNotesPage', { contact: contact}) }>
                  <Text>test Contact</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            }
            />
    );
  }
}

ContactNotesPage.js:

export default class ContactNotesPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("ContactNotesPage:constructor");
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    console.log("ContactNotesPage:render()");
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {
          console.log("ContactNotesPage:delete");
            Realm.write(() => { Realm.delete(params.contact);});
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ContactsPage');
        }
       }>
      <Text>DeleteContact</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
};

// main.js
const MainStack = StackNavigator({
  ContactsPage: {
    screen: ContactsPage,
  },
  ContactNotesPage:{
    screen: ContactNotesPage,
  },
});

export default MainStack;
```

Comment: You might want to move `this.updateContactsFromDB = this.updateContactsFromDB.bind(this);` to `componentWillMount(props){`

Comment: seems like a problem when: using react-navigation and realm while passing an object to the navigation and then delete this object. when passing contactID and make the delete using contactID, it works fine:                 let currContact = Realm.objects('Contact').filtered('recordID="'+params.contactID+'"');
                Realm.delete(currContact);

Comment: Did you try my guess?

Comment: Yes. same result (Accessing object of type Contact which has been invalidated or deleted...)

Comment: Why do you need the snapshot collection?

Comment: I don't. I added it as I thought it might solve the problem.

Comment: seems like there is an open bug at: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1031

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug in realm/react-navigation. when passing a parameter which is a realm object - if you delete this object your next navigation will fail.
A bug is already open at https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1031

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you get an object from realm (using realm.objects('collection')) and use realm.close() function on it. Either use Object.assign method or destructuring object or array approach to mitigate this problem. Like below,

```
const realmObject = realm.objects('collection');
const obj = [...realmObject] or {...realmObject[0]}; // the later one when filtered is used on realmObject.
```

My solution was that I did not call realm.close() because I was constantly engaged with the database.

https://realm.io/docs/javascript/0.14.0/api/Realm.html#close

Answer (score 0):

i used useFocusEffect from @react-navigation/native after delete item in array for update list array like this

```
//state to check get data ability: 

 const [getDataAbility, setGetDataAbility] = useState(true);        
  //useFocusEffect

   useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
           if (getDataAbility === true) {
            // handle data
           }
      }, [ dependencies... ]),
   );
 // catch error ""accessing obj of..."
 try {
       console.log(pickingItem.id);
   } catch (error) {
    setGetDataAbility(false);
    console.log('err picking: ', error);
   }
```

-> solve

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me:

```js
async function updateRealm() {
  const realm = Realm.open({
    schemas: [
      /*myschemas*/
    ]
  });

    realm.addListener('change', () => {
      /* consult function */
    });

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).